# Difference between TrustManager and KeyManager

Tags: java, https

I am trying to bring out the difference between TrustManager and keyManager used in HTTPS connection.It would be helpful,if references for the same are posted as i am not able to get the correct info.

Thanks and regards,
Surendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but which platform? I suppose Java.

TrustManager is for trusting the server certificate, KeyManager is for authentication on the server by the java client.

If you are connecting to an HTTPS server without (certificate) authentication you need only the TrustManager.

If the server requiers authentication you need both.

Comment: Apologies it is java platform :(